# How to use the .head() method of a pandas styler object?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I am working with a very big data set (18000 rows of data) which I only want to show a couple of rows such as 5 or 10 first rows. I was trying to use `pandas.DataFrame().head(10)` method but I am doing some styling and formatting and I receive the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'head'
```

This is how the styling looks like:

```
df.style.set_table_styles([{'props': [('font-size', '9pt'), 
                                            ('line-height', '100%')]}])
```

What is the best solution to this?

Comment: Have you tried saving the result of `pandas.DataFrame().head(10)` in a temporary variable and then apply your style on this variable ?

Comment: show more code.

Answer (score 3):

I actually figured I could use the `.head()` method before assigning the styling to the data frame as follows:

```
df_ = df.head(10).style.set_table_styles([{'props': [('font-size', '9pt'), 
                                            ('line-height', '100%')]}])
df_
```

This worked quit well. Thank you for the comments.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `df` that is already styled (of type pandas.io.formats.style.Styler), you can export the style, select head (using `.data` to access pandas.core.frame.DataFrame object), and then reuse the style:

```
style = df.export()
df.data.head(10).style.use(style)
```